R markdown with python/reticulate - No module named pandas
I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError for pandas immediately after being told pandas is installed.
Here is simplified code that shows the problem.
{r echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path=list(python='/mnt/c/Users/steve/workspace/EDGI/EEW-ReportCard-Data/venv/bin/python'))
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create('venv')
py_install('pandas', envname='venv')

u <- import('pandas')

When I run this chunk I get this puzzling result, first saying that the pandas requirement is satisfied, then that the modules is not found. What am I missing?
> knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path=list(python='/mnt/c/Users/steve/workspace/EDGI/EEW-ReportCard-Data/venv/bin/python'))
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create('venv')
py_install('pandas', envname='venv')

u <- import('pandas')
> library(reticulate)
> virtualenv_create('venv')
virtualenv: venv
> py_install('pandas', envname='venv')
Using virtual environment 'venv' ...
+ /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-user pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.9.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3 in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.24.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/steve/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
> 
> u <- import('pandas')
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

I'm using R version 3.6.3, Python version 3.8.10, Ubuntu 22.04 on wsl.

Telling knitr in WSL to use python from Windows host seems rather strange. But regarding your "No module" issue, is that venv the one that's actually active?  What do you get for  reticulate::py_exe()  when running it before and/or after import('pandas')  ? Does package list form reticulate::py_list_packages() make sense?

It is using python from the Ubuntu installed in wsl, not from Windows.

Thank you @margusl!
The problem was that my virtualenv_create() and py_install('pandas') were making and installing in a new venv in ~/.virtualvenvs, but my import('pandas') was working in ./venv, because that was what was set in knitr::opts_chunk$set().

Thanks to @margusl! The problem was that my virtualenv_create() and py_install('pandas') were making and installing in a new venv in ~/.virtualvenvs, but my import('pandas') was working in ./venv, because that was what was set in knitr::opts_chunk$set().
{r echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path=list(python='/mnt/c/Users/steve/workspace/EDGI/EEW-ReportCard-Data/venv/bin/python'))
library(reticulate)
py_install('pandas', envname='/mnt/c/Users/steve/workspace/EDGI/EEW-ReportCard-Data/venv')

u <- import('pandas')

